# Is there a way to use limitless lists in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a randomly-generated 2-d game, which I plan to do with a list of terrain to the right of the spawn point and a list of terrain to the left of the spawn point.  However, I need these lists to not have a length limit, as I want the world to be infinite.  If I can't find a way I will make the world "round" but infinite would be preferable.  Is this possible?

Comment: You could make the world a specific size then just have it wrap around when you reach the border.

Comment: If you've got free movement, how would you handle the case where your world grows bigger than your physical memory? You can easily pretend that your list is practically limitless but in reality you'd have to start throwing away the furthest elements.

Comment: But if the question is only about how to create lazily constructed lists, the answer is much simpler and straightforward :)

Comment: How to you intend to store an infinite world in a finite amount of memory?

Answer (score 2):

An ArrayList is infinite... until memory runs out. But I guess that was not the question.

Update: Right, this is limited even though I argue nobody will notice the world restarting after two billion units.

Thought about that again. What you need is a random function that creates the same value again and again when you give it seed and current position.  So you do not store the world, you recalculate it on the fly.

So you need an infinite counter only for the position in your world. The only challenge will be the storage of event results such us eaten mushrooms and destroyed bridges.

Comment: An array list is not infinite. Underlying is an array which has a maximum of `pow(2, 32)` values.

Answer (score 1):

Storing all the data in a list will have a lot of limitations.

If you use an `ArrayList`, you can't have infinite elements.
If you use a `LinkedList`, you lose random access, so speed is a lot slower.

And for any list, RAM is an issue.

---

You'd be better off by splitting generated areas into chunks, then storing those to the harddrive.

Now, you'd still want a list of loaded areas, but this will be limited by a scope. If you're 2 game-miles to the East of some town, no point keeping the town information in reference (I hope).

---

One very popular game to this is Minecraft. Attempting to load the entire Minecraft world into your RAM won't happen - yet it still has the potential for infinite worlds.

Comment: And if you're really clever about it, you can hide all this detail and to the outside it can be presented as an infinite list. The only problem with it is indexing, which has to be done with a datatype that can represent arbitrarily big numbers. Which in Java would be `BigInteger`, but the overhead of it can be punitive and not worth the hassle. After all, `long` can represent as big a number of screens as you'd realistically be able to store on disk.

Answer (score 1):

If the world is going to be huge, I wouldn't store it in an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`. Instead you can make the whole world depend on a randomly selected `long` value `seed`. The terrain at position `i` can then be found using `new Random(seed ^ i).nextInt()` (or something). That way the world will be (effectively) infinite and you won't have to save the terrain in memory. Whenever you return to a previously visited part of the world it will be the same as it was before. The number of different worlds is 2^64 so you'd have to live a very long time before you saw the same world again.

Comment: I like your idea, except for one thing: I want the player to be able to change the world.  This means that I do need to have it remember, but I think I will use the seed idea for the original generation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList can contain up to 2^31 values (because length of array is integer, which is unsigned 4 byte structure).

However LinkedList is limitless, the only limit is the memory of JVM.